# Ubuntu WiFi connection is very unstable

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking

I have Windows 8 and Ubuntu 14.04 dual booted on my laptop. Until last week, the WiFi on both Operating Systems were working perfectly. However, for the past few days my Ubuntu WiFi has been incredibly unstable. It disconnects itself from my University internet and refuses to connect back. The only way to fix this is to restart my computer which gives me 5 more minutes of internet and then it disconnects itself. On Windows there is no such problem.

I ran the script provided by Wild Man in his [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) to a similar question. [This](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9150838/) is the result of the script. I connect to the "NU-Student" wireless access point. Is there any way to fix this problem?

This problem is not just seen in Ubuntu 14.04. It also comes in 10.04 !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've experienced much better performance with this network card and a similar university wireless network (multiple access points) following the advice from this user:

https://zach-adams.com/2014/06/fixing-rtl8723ae-driver-ubuntu-linux/

In short, two stages:

1. Try installing the linux-firmware-nonfree drivers with this command:

   `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree`
2. Try installing the WICD network manager. For instructions for your version of Ubuntu, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD

Answer (score 1):

Your wireless is attempting to roam from among several access points, each with the same EESID, NU-Student. You are connected, at the time the wireless script was run, to one with a signal strength of 37, although nearby, there is another with a signal strength of 70. Your message log also shows disconnects and reconnects to several different access points all named NU-Student.

I suggest you do:

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
```

Find the MAC address of the NU-Student access point with the highest signal strength and ask Network Manager to bind to it only by editing connections and specifying the MAC in the box 'BSSID' like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMCtj.png Of course, specify your details.

Next, I'd delete the erroneous connection profiles:

```
sudo rm /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/NU-Student
sudo rm /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/NU-Student\ 1
```

Then restart Network manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Any improvement?

You might also try a driver parameter:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723ae
sudo modprobe rtl8723ae swenc=1
```

If it helps, make it permanent:

```
sudo -i
echo "options rtl8723ae swenc=1" >> /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723ae.conf
exit
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried everything you said. However, every time I put in a BSSID from the result of the first command, the connection refuses to connect. It keeps asking me for the WiFi password but never connects. I've tried 4 different BSSID's of NU-Student.

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work :( Really appreciate your help though